# Fixing error 'slice' error to add list of elements in separate Excel cells

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to get the list of colours in an image to be listed in separate cells in an excel sheet along with the count and percentage

I have managed to transfer data to excel sheet but it was all combined in one cell. I have searched how to do it but now I am getting

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Here is what I have tried

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter
import prettytable

img = Image.open("Original 2.JPG")
size = w, h = img.size
data = img.load()

colors = []
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        color = data[x, y]
        hex_color = '#'+''.join([hex(c)[2:].rjust(2, '0') for c in color])
        colors.append(hex_color)

#pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Color', 'Count', 'Percentage'])

total = w * h

for color, count in Counter(colors).items():
    percent = int(count/total * 100)
    if percent > 0:
        #         pt.add_row([color, count, percent])

        # print(pt, total)

        final = {'colors': [colors],
                 'count': [count],
                 'percent': [percent]
                 }

        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['colors'] = final[0::3]   <--------------Error returning from here
        df['count'] = final[1::3]
        df['percent'] = final[2::3]

        df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project\export_dataframe.xlsx',
                    index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code within your for loop really doesn't make sense.

<s>This if statement is *always* true, which makes it redundant:
`if percent > 0:`</s> Edit: Ignore this. The call to `int` can return `0`, which would cause this if statement to be false.

Everything below that, including writing to an excel file, is executed for every colour. Presumably this is an indentation error.

```py
df['colors'] = final[0::3]   <--------------Error returning from here
```

`final` is a `dict`. You need to access it using one of its 3 keys. For example: `final['colors']`, which would return the entire list of pixel colours, including duplicates.

What you want can be achieved with this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter
import prettytable

img = Image.open("Original 2.JPG")
size = w, h = img.size
data = img.load()

colors = []
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        color = data[x, y]
        hex_color = '#'+''.join([hex(c)[2:].rjust(2, '0') for c in color])
        colors.append(hex_color)

#pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Color', 'Count', 'Percentage'])

total = w * h

colors, counts = zip(*Counter(colors).items())
percentages = tuple(count / total for count in counts)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['colors'] = colors
df['count'] = counts
df['percent'] = percentages

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project\export_dataframe.xlsx',
            index=False, header=True)
```

The 2 key lines are:

```py
colors, counts = zip(*Counter(colors).items())
percentages = tuple(count / total for count in counts)
```

The first line creates 2 `tuples` with all the unique colours and their counts. A tuple is basically an immutable `list`. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) combined with the `*` unpacking operator is used to transform the *key* and *value* pairs from `Counter(colors).items()` to their own separate tuples.

The second line creates a tuple from a *generator expression* which gives us the percentages of all the colours.

`colors`, `counts`, and `percentages` are all aligned so the same index refers to the same colour.

Comment: You would think that his "if statement is always true" but it is not. Before he enclosed it in int() which was rounding it to zero ;) The more pixels and colours, the highest chance that it will be actually False ;)

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use lists over dictionary. I have not seen any particular advantage. I also removed both removed `int()` from:

```
percent = int(count/total * 100)
```

and

```
if percent > 0:
```

Because if you have image with many hues of colours, the condition would never be passed.

The complete code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from collections import Counter

img = Image.open("Original 2.JPG")
size = w, h = img.size
data = img.load()

colors = []
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        color = data[x, y] 
        hex_color = '#'+''.join([hex(c)[2:].rjust(2, '0') for c in color])
        colors.append(hex_color)

total = w * h

color_hex = []
color_count = []
color_percent =[]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for color, count in Counter(colors).items():
    percent = count/total * 100 # Do not make it int. Majority of colors are < 1%, unless you want >= 1%
    color_hex.append(color)
    color_count.append(count)
    color_percent.append(percent)

df['color'] = color_hex
df['count'] = color_count
df['percent'] = color_percent


df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project\export_dataframe.xlsx',
                    index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: I never noticed the `int` in `percent = int(count/total * 100)`, so the `if percent > 0` could actually fail. Good pick-up.